# ¿Podrian ayudarme a encontrar el error?, me marca error de sql

Tags: java, phpmyadmin

```
 /**
     * Descripcion: metodo para buscar un producto Recibe: recibe un objheto de
     * tipo producto Devuelve: un registro de tipo producto
     */
    public static Almacen buscarAlmacen(Almacen almac) {
        ResultSet rs;
        Usuarios usu = new Usuarios();
        Productos prod = new Productos();

        if (con != null) {
            try {
// consulta con condición 
                String sentecia = "SELECT alamcen.idAlamcen,\n"
                        + "                                          usuarios.nombre, \n"
                        + "                                          productos.nombreProducto,\n"
                        + "                                          alamcen.codigo\n"
                        + "                                          FROM alamcen\n"
                        + "                            INNER JOIN productos on productos.idProductos = alamcen.Productos_idProductos\n"
                        + "                            INNER JOIN usuarios on usuarios.idUsuarios = alamcen.Usuarios_idUsuarios"
                        //where condicion mediante el ccodigo recibido del objeto producto
                        + "WHERE codigo = " + almac.getCodigo() + "";
                PreparedStatement pst2;
                pst2 = con.prepareStatement(sentecia);
                rs = pst2.executeQuery();
// condicion: si la consulta arroja un registro entonces me llena el objeto
                if (rs.next()) {

                    almac.setIdAlmacen(rs.getInt(1));

                    usu.setNombre(rs.getString(2));
                    almac.setIdUsuario(usu);

                    prod.setNombreProducto(rs.getString(3));
                    almac.setIdProductos(prod);

                    almac.setCodigo(rs.getInt(4));
                }

            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                System.out.println("Error al Buscar" + sqle.getMessage());
            }
        }
//OBJETO RESULTANTE

        return almac;

    }

    public static ArrayList<Almacen> getBuscarAlmacens(Almacen almac) {
        ArrayList<Almacen> listaAlmacen = new ArrayList<>();

        ResultSet rs;
        Statement st;
        Connection con = ConexionBD.obtenerConexion();
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                st = con.createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT alamcen.idAlamcen,\n"
                        + "                                usuarios.nombre, \n"
                        + "                                productos.nombreProducto,\n"
                        + "                                alamcen.codigo\n"
                        + "                 FROM alamcen\n"
                        + "               INNER JOIN productos on productos.idProductos = alamcen.Productos_idProductos\n"
                        + "               INNER JOIN usuarios on usuarios.idUsuarios = alamcen.Usuarios_idUsuarios"
                        //where condicion mediante el ccodigo recibido del objeto producto
                        + "WHERE codigo = " + almac.getCodigo() + "");

                int i = 0;
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Almacen alma = new Almacen();
                    Usuarios usu = new Usuarios();
                    Productos prod = new Productos();

                    alma.setIdAlmacen(rs.getInt(1));

                    usu.setNombre(rs.getString(2));
                    alma.setIdUsuario(usu);

                    prod.setNombreProducto(rs.getString(3));
                    alma.setIdProductos(prod);

                    alma.setCodigo(rs.getInt(4));

                    listaAlmacen.add(i, alma);
                    i++;

                }
                st.close();
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                System.out.println("Error" + sqle.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return listaAlmacen;
    }
```

Comment: el error que marca es: ErrorYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'codigo = 543' at line 7
conexion realizada

Comment: El manejador de base de datos no es un editor de textos para que le coloques saltos de página `\n`. Debes sustituir `\n` por un espacio donde haga falta y eliminar todos los `\n`.

Comment: @A.Cedano y OP. El único problema es que faltaba un espacio antes del `WHERE`. Un motor de base de datos decente puede omitir el procesamiento de los caracteres de salto de línea.

Comment: Significa que MySQL no es un motor de bd _decente_. Acabo de probarlo y me da un error de sintaxis. Además, ¿tiene algún sentido escribir consultas así, con saltos de línea? Tampoco es el _único_ problema, ya que es una consulta vulnerable @LuiggiMendozaJ

Comment: @A.Cedano sí, es una consulta vulnerable, y el código tiene más problemas, pero primero se atiende el problema de fondo que es el error de sintaxis en el query y es por la falta de un espacio.

Comment: A mi me da error de sintaxis la consulta construida con `\n`, aparte de que no tiene ninguna utilidad, de hecho, es la primera vez que veo una consulta escrita así. En la respuesta se ofrece una solución global a los principales problemas. ¿O corregimos sólo el espacio que falta en el WHERE y que abra otra pregunta para lo demás? El OP tiene derecho a saber que los saltos de línea podrían traerle problemas, y que es mejor que se olvide de ellos al escribir las consultas, @LuiggiMendozaJ

Answer (score 0):

El manejador de base de datos no es un editor de textos para que le coloques saltos de línea `\n`. Debes sustituir `\n` por un espacio donde haga falta y eliminar todos los `\n`.

También usa una consulta preparada, pues del modo actual estás desperdiciando uno de los puntos fuertes de los preparedStatement, que es proteger nuestras consultas de la Inyección SQL. Si donde va el código alguien escribe esto: 
`X100; DROP TABLE cualquier-tabla; --` de ese modo cualquier usuario malicioso podría borrar tus tablas y enviar consultas mucho más peligrosas.

Para proteger la consulta, en `sentencia` sustituyes el valor por el cual quieres filtrar por un signo de interrogación `?`  y luego pasas dicho valor usando el preparedStatement, usando `setString, setInt, setDate...`  según el tipo de dato de esa columna.

```
            String sentecia = "SELECT alamcen.idAlamcen, "
                    + "usuarios.nombre, "
                    + "productos.nombreProducto, "
                    + "alamcen.codigo "
                    + "FROM alamcen "
                    + "INNER JOIN productos on productos.idProductos = alamcen.Productos_idProductos "
                    + "INNER JOIN usuarios on usuarios.idUsuarios = alamcen.Usuarios_idUsuarios "
                    //where condicion mediante el ccodigo recibido del objeto producto
                    + "WHERE codigo = ?";
```

Luego, pasas el parámetro:

```
            PreparedStatement pst2;
            pst2 = con.prepareStatement(sentecia);
            pst2.setString(1,almac.getCodigo());
            // Si codigo fuese un entero: pst2.setInt(1,almac.getCodigo());
            rs = pst2.executeQuery();

... resto del código.
```

Sobre el uso correcto de PreparedStatemente, [consultar la documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Y como nota curiosa, ¿la tabla se llama `alamcen` o `almacen`?

Comment: ok esta bien, si quitare los saltos de linea y se llama alamcen ya que por error le puse ese nombre pero lo cambiare, muchas gracias

Comment: @UliBaeza Te funciono? Creo que el problema era que estabas pasando un entero a un campo que posiblemente sea tipo texto. Entonces la solución de A. Cedano te va a poner comillas automáticamente.

Comment: si muchas gracias